# Capture [a-zA-Z] except for specific sequence of characters ("PT")

Tags: regex

I have this capturing subgroup in my regex statement. What I am trying to achieve is to add an exception to the bold/first matching group (**[a-zA-Z]{2}**) which should not match the specific word "PT". I am using VBScript.RegEx which is said to be similar to Javascript RegEx.

```
([a-zA-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z]{1}\d{1}|\d{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})
```

Refer to the table below for the decision tree.

| word | match |
| --- | --- |
| AA | Pass |
| A1 | Pass |
| 1A | Pass |
| PT | Fail |
| pt | Fail |
| pT | Fail |

Comment: Use `(?!pt)[A-Z]{2}` and set `IgnoreCase` to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *negative lookahead conditional*:

```
(?![Pp][Tt])\w{2}
```

The `(?!` means the next two characters should *not* match the value inside the parenthesis, in this case `[Pp][Tt]`.

[Try it on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UCzxHi/1)

Comment: There is a duplicate that covers *all* the "exception" regex matching, including this case.

Comment: @Nick Sorry about that, I did try viewing the other existing threads however I did not see the duplicate referred just now.

Comment: @mousetail Works perfectly, I was trying to make conditionals work but this is what I actually needed.